# Cocoapods Push Changes in Source Code to Remote Repo

Tags: xcode, repository, cocoapods

I have forked a few Github projects and added my own modifications to them. I then load these pods using cocoapods from my forked remote. When I am in the xcode project, how can I push the changes that I have made in the pods back to my forked remote repo?

I understand that you can load pods from local repos and any changes you make are made in the source files of that local repo. Then you can push that repo back to the remote. This won't work for me though because I am developing on multiple machines, so I need to load the pods from the remote. Is there a solution to this? How can I push my changes back to my remote repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `:path` option is not viable for you, the `:git` directive of the Podfile DSL should be what you are after. The caveat is that you need to commit after every patch.

There is a plan for a [powerful feature](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1010), which, according to my comprehension of you issue, would be the most appropriate solution for this case. But it hasn't been implemented yet.